# js and css files experience 7-8 second delay pushing via Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, css, dreamweaver, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a very odd issue.  A new dev server (win 2008r2 Standard) has been built.  The team uses Dreamweaver (CS5.5) to push files to environments.   For some reason .js and .css files get pushed to dev (100% they are there instantly.  we can see then land in another RDP session)  but are not accessible for around 7-8 seconds.  The browser does not error of course.  if its a .css file they styles are all dropped.

We have QA and internalProdcution server which we also push code to.  These are almost identical, they are win 2008r2 Enterprise.  This issue does not occur. When the files are pushed they are immediacy brows-able.

If we open to explorer windows (one local, one the application dir of the new dev server)  make a chamge and copy/paste the file using explorer no issue occurs!  This makes me think Dreamweaver is the issue, but why does it not occue pushing to QA or intProd?    The site properties/setup in DW has been tripple checked, they are the same.

What could this be, its very annoying!!

Comment: What does your server actually use for the web server? It sounds like caching or a slow file notify hook or something. Also this question feels Super User-y to me.